# The Break command in C not working properly?

Tags: c

I'm writing a dice blackjack program from Lab and in order to do it I'm using the break command. In the code below, if the player rolls over 21 on the first hand it is meant to break out of the while loop and go to the code below it but that is not happening. I know it gets through the if because it prints "You busted! Back Luck!" but the break statement does not seem to be working. What am I doing wrong??

```
while(1) { //Loop for each round
    rollDie(&roll1, &roll2);
    printf("Your first roll is %d and %d \n", roll1, roll2);
    count = (roll1 + roll2)*2;
    check = count;
    printf("This totals to %d. Doubling this we get %d as your current hand.\n", roll1+roll2, count);

    if(count > 21) {
        printf("You busted! Bad luck!");
        break;
    }

    while(flag == 1) {
        playerMove = getPlayerMove();
        if(playerMove == 'H' || playerMove == 'h')
            flag = hitMe(&count, &check);

        if(flag == 2)
            break;
        else
            flag = 0;
    }

    printf("It is now the dealers turn to roll.");
    flag = dealer(count, &total);

    if(total > count)
        printf("The dealers %d beats your %d", total, count);
    else if (total == count) {
        printf("It's a tie!");
    }
    else
        printf("Your %d beats the dealers %d", count, total);

    break;
}
```

Comment: could you give the whole output? did that print `You busted! Bad luck!` then `It is now the dealers turn to roll.` followed?

Comment: What followed was the playerMove function inside the following while loop which asks if the player would like to Hit or Stand. I never entered an answer for that, I just terminated the program cuz it's never supposed to get there D:

Comment: This is C not python you must add braces wherever needed

Comment: Use a debugger and step though the code line by line, the problem should be very easy to find then.

Comment: maybe it's better for you to single step through it.

Comment: For large values of `1` your code will not work

Comment: `while(true)` in C? Good luck with that. Personally I prefer `for(;;)` as fewer compilers emit a warning.

Comment: @Bathsheba Oops, I edited it.

Comment: As a tip: you almost never want to phrase a question as if it is a problem with the programming language; it's not about 99.9999% of the time. It's almost always going to be a problem with how you're using it, so phrase your question accordingly.

Comment: Abstracting everything out to the while and if leads to this:  http://ideone.com/9DQc4h as you can see, it runs once only then terminates (as expected). _are you sure that what you described is what is happening in your program?_ Try stepping through in a debugger, or maybe provide runnable code so we can test it.

Answer (score 5):

Your indentation is wrong. That might be an indication that your code doesn't do what you think it does. An "else" goes together with the "if" just before it, not the one you think.

Comment: according to OP's description, if `You busted! Bad luck!` is printed, the outter loop has been broken already.

Comment: Oh, I see where I messed up there. But that shouldn't effect the fact of the break; not breaking out of the while loop like it should in this case should it?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(playerMove == 'H' || playerMove == 'h')
        flag = hitMe(&count, &check);
        if(flag == 2)
            break;
    else
        flag = 0;
```

Here is the problem. else is not counted as else paired with first if

```
if(playerMove == 'H' || playerMove == 'h')
```

It is paired with last if

```
if(flag == 2)
```

Solution: Use {} delimiters to define from where your bodies of if and else are starting and where they are ending. Its good practice. Now you know why.

Comment: But unless my understanding of break is wrong, it should never get this far right? I agree that's an error if it gets that far in the code which I will fix now, but shouldn't the code below break; be skipped?

Comment: If control reaches to break statement (in this case if flag ==2) then control will break out of loop, but unless this condition is not true loop will continue to run.

Comment: @MurtazaZaidi you didn't understand OP. the problem is the first break, you are talking about the second one.